# storing passwords in sql server database using ef core code first

Tags: c#, authentication, passwords, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this class to represent my users:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

A simplistic version of my register method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
Register(User newUser)
{
    ...
    _context.add(newUser);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    ...
}
```

So my question is: Should I alter the password type from a regular string before storing?  If so, to what data type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**YES YES YES**

## Never store passwords as plain text

While much of this is a security discussion rather than a programming one, you should only be storing a secure hash (PBKDF2, Argon, and Bcrypt are current standards) along with a unique salt used for that hash.

Storing it as you are is just asking someone to steal your database and get all your users passwords without any more effort than reading the `Password` column (which they probably reused a million other places).

Its still OK to store it as `string` though.

The `DataType.Password` is just an annotation for consumers of your class to read. (per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx). It does **not** enhance security from a storage/database perspective.

Comment: So does the DataType(DataType.Password) annotation for the class property not encrypt or hash the password at all?

Answer (score 1):

You should *never* store a password in the database if you can avoid it.  Best practice is to store a salted, irreversible hash of the password.

Typically this would be a SHA2 or PBKDF2, or whatever of the password salted with something that cannot change about the user-- e.g. the ID of the record.

You would store the has typically as a varbinary(32) or whatever length your hash algorithm uses.

This approach means that you cannot determine a user's password, since it is irreversible.  To test a password of someone attempting to login, perform the same hash with the same salt, and test if the result is the same as what you have in your database.  This way, a hacker who gets your database cannot figure out what each user's password is, but you can still test if a user knows their own password.

Comment: What does DataType.Password DataAnnotation do for the property then?

Comment: The problem with MD5/SHA1 is not necessarily collisions (though that is *a* problem), its that they are easily crackable with consumer hardware. PBKDF2, BCrypt, SCrypt, etc. are designed to be *slow* so brute-force attacks are much harder (often requiring specialized FPGAs)

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure for more

Comment: I desperately added a bunch of tags to posts just to get to 50 rep so I could stick a comment on this post saying how bad of an idea it is to use MD5 etc for passwords, but BradleyDotNET beat me to it.

I still want to reiterate that it's a terrible idea.