# Why my code is not reading the next condition in if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

Why isn't my code reading the next condition in the if statement?

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from admin where Username='" + txtuser.Text + "'  and Password='" + txtpass.Text + "' ", con);

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
    if (txtuser.Text == dr["Username"].ToString() && txtpass.Text == dr["Password"].ToString())
    {

        this.Hide();
        Form f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Show();
    }
    else if (txtuser.Text != dr["Username"].ToString() && txtpass.Text == dr["Password"].ToString())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        clear();
    }
    else if (txtuser.Text == dr["Username"].ToString() && txtpass.Text != dr["Password"].ToString())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        clear();
    }
    else if (txtuser.Text == "" & txtpass.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Username and Password!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    }
    else if (txtuser.Text == "" && txtpass.Text != "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Username!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        clear();
    }
    else if (txtuser.Text != "" && txtpass.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Password!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        clear();
    }
    else if (txtuser.Text != dr["Username"].ToString() && txtpass.Text != dr["Password"].ToString())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username and Password!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Regardless of your current problem, your code has two massive problems which are **way bigger**. a) You need to read up on SQL Injection. b) You need to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634489/storing-passwords-in-sql-server-database-using-ef-core-code-first/42634547#42634547 .

Comment: `else if (txtuser.Text != dr["Username"].ToString() && txtpass.Text != dr["Password"].ToString())` Have a think about why this check makes no sense? Could your query return a row such that that `if` would ever return `true`?

Comment: So, now your code has changed. Which is the real code? The original code, or the new code?

Comment: When you debug through the code, what happened, and what did you **expect** to happen (and why)? **Debug through, line by line.**

Comment: 1. Use parameterized queries. 2. Don't use `ExecuteReader`, select 1 and use `Execute scalar`. check if there returned object is null or has a value. 3. Don't store passwords as plain text. Store a salted hash instead. 4. Don't let the user know if it's the password or the username that's wrong. You are only helping hackers by giving them information. Always reply with "invalid username or password",

Comment: Use a debugger to see where you are going wrong. Do a careful analysis step by step. See what variables are being returned by your query and how you are using them. It will help you solve your logical errors.

Comment: Your query will either return a row where both the username and password match the input, or it will return nothing at all. It can't possibly return a row with a matching username but not password, or any other combination. And take note of what @ZoharPeled said - never, ever, ever put user input into a sql query by string concatenation!

Answer (score -3):

in case of  && condition  in C# if  1st become false then next condition is not going to  be validated