# How to get data from database after checking if the data exists

Tags: c#, sql

I'm setting up a log-in form with 2 users which are "admin" and "user". If the user exists in the database, I need to get the [usertype](https://snag.gy/Q6rZzm.jpg) after I supply the username and password. I have 2 textboxes for username and password(for input) and another textbox for usertype(to view what usertype). How can I display the usertype when username and password is being checked from the database? Please help. Thank you.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "select * from [USER] where username= '" + Unametb.Text + "' and userpw='" + Pwordtb.Text + "'";
            using (SqlConnection xcon = new SqlConnection(@"Server=KINGARTHUR\SQLEXPRESS;Database=CENTER;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand xcom = new SqlCommand(query, xcon))
                {
                    SqlDataReader xreader;
                    try
                    {
                        if (Unametb.Text.Equals("") && Pwordtb.Text.Equals(""))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Username & Password is Empty!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        }
                        else if (Unametb.Text.Equals(""))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Username is Empty!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        }
                        else if (Pwordtb.Text.Equals(""))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Password is Empty!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            xcon.Open();
                            xreader = xcom.ExecuteReader();
                            int count = 0;

                            while (xreader.Read())
                            {
                                count = count + 1;
                            }
                            if (count == 1)
                            {
                                textBox1.Text = xreader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                                Form b = new Form();
                                b.Show();
                                this.Hide();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password do not match!");
                            }
                            loginuser.user = Unametb.Text;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        xcon.Close();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the colums of USER :  https://snag.gy/Q6rZzm.jpg

Comment: When you debug through, what is the value of `xreader.GetValue(3).ToString();`? Also, put an extra line of code inside the `while` loop. That line of code should be `var bob = xreader.GetValue(3).ToString();` What is the value of `bob` after it is assigned?

Comment: You are putting the value in a textbox in the form, then you immediately hide the form. How do you expect the user to be able to see it? Did you mean to put it in the new form?

Comment: @mjwills Thank you so much for the help! I've been trying to find solution for these for days. I'm still learning c#. Thank you so much!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321338/why-my-code-is-not-reading-the-next-condition-in-if-statement for some further advice.

Comment: Please create a new question for that.